# como paso esta consulta [ de mysql a sqlserver?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
SELECT id_rubro, rubro, name_e AS Empresas
FROM dbs_empresas, p_rubros
WHERE rubro_id = id_rubro AND activa_e='Y'
GROUP BY rubro
ORDER BY rubro
```

me sale este error

> Mens. 8120, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
>   Column 'e_rubros.id_rubro' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: En realidad, no porque la consulta corría en MySQL quiere decir que te estaba dando los resultados correctos. MySQL es notorio por permitir consultas inválidas, en particular en la forma como te permite usar el `GROUP BY`. Por favor describe tus tablas y cómo debe funcionar tu consulta. Tristemente,en tuconsulta, ni siquiera es claro cual columna pertenece a qué tabla.

Comment: Si haces lo que @sstan dice, obtendrás la respuesta correcta mucho más rápido.

Comment: Como dice sstan, sin saber a que tabla pertenece cada columna es difícil escribir una respuesta completa. En principio dos cosas para señalarte, en SQLServer cada columna del `SELECT` debe estar en el `GROUP BY`, en tu caso: sería `GROUP BY id_rubro, rubro, name_e`, con eso deberíamos resolver el error, luego no uses `JOINS` implícitos, es algo que está deprecado hace mucho, usa la forma explícita mediante `INNER JOIN`, `JEFT JOIN`, etc. (y agrega alias de tablas).

Answer (score 0):

Aunque mysql te permite esta consulta piensa que no tiene mucho sentido. Sql Server es más consecuente y por eso te da el error que mencionas. Estás pidiendo que te agrupe filas con el mismo rubro y a la vez no estás diciendo que tiene que hacer con los campos id_rubro y name_e para cada grupo de rubro.

Tal y como te dice el error tienes dos opciones:

-Añades estas columnas en la cláusula group. Con esto harás que el agrupamiento se haga primero por rubro, después por id_rubro y después por name_e. Si para cada grupo estos valores son iguales obtendrás la misma respuesta que en mysql. Si no lo son comprobarás que la consulta arroja más resultados ya que se producen subgrupos por cada variación.

```
SELECT id_rubro, rubro, name_e AS Empresas
FROM dbs_empresas, p_rubros
WHERE rubro_id = id_rubro AND activa_e='Y'
GROUP BY rubro, id_rubro, name_e
ORDER BY rubro
```

-Especificas una función de agregado para que sepa como agrupar estos valores (por ejemplo la función MIN que te seleccionará el mínimo valor de cada agrupamiento).

```
SELECT MIN(id_rubro), rubro, MIN(name_e) AS Empresas
FROM dbs_empresas, p_rubros
WHERE rubro_id = id_rubro AND activa_e='Y'
GROUP BY rubro
ORDER BY rubro
```